# Is Graham's number bigger than the smallest inaccessible cardinal？

Tags: logic

Someone says Graham's number is the biggest number with a name.

Is Graham's number bigger than the smallest inaccessible cardinal？

Comment: Mauro's answer is complete; I'll comment on the claim that Graham's number is the greatest number with a name. Here is the description of a greater number: "the number x s.t. x = Graham's number + 1". If Graham's number exists and is unique, then that description picks out a unique existing number, so we can name it "User136774's number"..

Comment: Graham's number is finite. "Someone" is wrong.

Comment: @user4894: that depends on whether infinite cardinals are "numbers". Still: any infinite cardinal whatsoever (including Aleph-0) is larger than Graham's number. Graham's number's notoriety comes from being a natural number with that status.

Comment: @Hunan Rostomyan I claim Graham's number to the Graham's number as user4894's number. So there!

Comment: @user4894 I'm not sure I understand your point. If you want to let "user494's number" denote g^g where g is Graham's number, you're welcome to do that. What are you trying to say.

Comment: @Hunan Rostomyan I said exactly what you said! Now I'm really confused.

Comment: @user4894 We're on the same page. My point was that natural numbers are closed under succession, but yes, it's also true that natural numbers are closed under exponentiation. Succession in this case is preferable to exponentiation because given an arbitrary natural k, k < (k+1); while ~(k > k^k) for k={0, 1}.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan - please, be careful not to reproduce the fallacy of "the biggest number namebale in less than ..."; i.e. when we say "Graham's number is the greatest number with a name", we are **not** saying "the name of the biggest number" (absurd) but "the biggest number (up today) baptized with a *proper name*" (like, in the field of the real, e or pi).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, I've tried to be very careful here. So far I've said only that (1) there is no biggest natural number; and (2) I've baptized the number next to Graham's number, which certainly exists and is unique, with a proper name, namely "User136774's number". Yes, that number isn't as popular, yet :P, as the transcendentals you mentioned, but User136774 might be working towards that.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan - well done ! :)

Comment: DV because it's a math question, not philosophy.

Comment: @tkruse, I wasn't sure initially if it is correct to consider naming in this context as properly mathematical, but if we're talking about Graham's number, I think I agree that even qua naming, it would be reasonable to show via Godel codes that one can answer this question in a properly mathematical way.

Answer (score 2):

See in Wiki the article about [Large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_numbers) including *Graham's number* :

> Although all these numbers above are very large, they are all still **decidedly finite**. Certain fields of mathematics define infinite and transfinite numbers. For example, aleph-null is the cardinality of the infinite set of natural numbers, and aleph-one is the next greatest cardinal number. c is the cardinality of the reals. The proposition that c = aleph-1 is known as the continuum hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, there is no "largest number with a name" in the sense in which there is no "largest prime number" - one can always show that there is a bigger one! (in this case by naming its successor)